# How to resolve system error i.e -This application was unable to start correctly(0*c0000022)

Tags: redis, windows-7-x64

I am trying to run redis server in my system. When I typed redis-server by moving through that redis directory it is showing me the following error. I am using windows-7 64 bit machine.

```
Error:

This application was unable to start correctly(0*c0000022).click ok to close the application.
```

Comment: does system event viewer have anything related?

Comment: Actually i can not know.Please can you give the solution for it @akonsu .?